# JSLinter for Maven 2

Tags: maven, jslint, jslint4java

I am looking for an automated way to validate my JS code during Maven build process.
One of the projects I found is JSlint4Java. What I discovered the hard way, it works only with Maven 3, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

You could try Wro4j with JSHint. It works great in my projects.

https://code.google.com/p/wro4j/

Answer (score 0):

well I dont any way about maven. but Hudson build tool also have integration with JSLint. Maybe you can integrate with your build server